# I want to only fetch a specific field data

Tags: python, django

[image]Hello in my order model i have these fields :

```
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product")
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField(datetime.datetime.today, null=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(
        Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    payment_method = models.ForeignKey(
        PaymentMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
total = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

From here i have total field where i want to create a result depend on quantity and price.For an example price * quantity = total

After that i want to fetch only the total

I am new in django really confused about this Please help

Answer (score 2):

You suppose to correct your `total` field indentation. I do not know whether it is mistake or you are trying to do that way.
what you suppose to do is.

```
   class Order:
        total = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

For that you can overload Save method of the model. This is the way you can do is:

```py
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total = self.quantity * self.price
        return super().save(self,*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: ok but how will be able to show the total ??

Comment: I did it correctly but its still showing blank

Comment: suppose you have a form and you add `quantity` and `price` once you will save the form you will get value in the total field. then you can show it in your template. as you show other values.

Comment: @Sakibovi The total field for previous data will still be empty. After you run migrations and then save it will save value for the total field.

Comment: You said overload save method how can I use it ?? in my model can u show me sample ??

Comment: i ran the data migration but still blank :(

Comment: He already did that `def save(self, *args, **kwargs):`

Comment: I know but its showing me blank brother :(

Comment: Yes i did. When i try to add new item it doesn't save into the database I have added a screenshot please chek

Comment: probably you are doing something wrong. This is the way you can achieve this. Make sure you saved the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Order(models.Model):
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    price = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        total = self.price * self.quantity
        return total
```